# et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate where Object name occurs twice

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I need to create a Task Activity Apex trigger for use in Marketing Cloud Connect Triggered Sends.

Here is the standard Marketing Cloud connector trigger code:

```
trigger Trig_Activity on Task (after insert, after update) {
    et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Task');
}
```

Unfortunately another installed package also contains a Task Object.

[image]

How do I code the trigger to only select Activity Tasks?

Comment: If an installed package has a `Task` object is should have a namespace and '__c' on it, ex: `PackageNamespace__Task__c`. Therefore, it won't fire the trigger on the ootb `Task`.

Comment: I wish that were true. For some reason, when in Marketing Cloud Connect setup, there appears two Task entries. i would show a screenshot, but not sure how to attach to this question

Comment: is pretty easy, there is an image button in the rich text editor where you post/edit your question.

Comment: hope this works ![Two Tasks Appearing in Object selection](http://image.exct.net/lib/fe6215707d6c057f7111/m/1/SMTab_2TaskObjects.png)
![View from Sales Cloud](http://image.exct.net/lib/fe6215707d6c057f7111/m/1/view-of-two-Task-Objects.jpg)

Comment: Yeah see the `BMCServiceDesk__Task__c`, that will not fire the SF ootb `Task`

Comment: Ok. I wonder why Task appears twice in the dropdown? and why when I am creating a Triggered Send for Task, the dropdown contains attributes from both of those Objects ![View from Triggered Send](http://image.exct.net/lib/fe6215707d6c057f7111/m/1/Need+Custom+Fields+in+Field+Criteria+dropdown.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The `Task` with the API name `BMCServiceDesk__Task__c` will not fire your trigger on the Salesforce `Task` object. So you don't need to worry about it. Even though there are two `Task` objects your trigger will only fire on the Salesforce `Task` object because your trigger is on that object.

```
trigger Trig_Activity on Task (after insert, after update) {
                          ^object the trigger is on
```

[image]

Long story short... What you have is correct and will work fine. :)